# Bash/Unix scripting: S3 Read Count of records

Tags: bash

Scenario: In order to find the .gz files from S3 Bucket and take the count on file level, below is the snippet of code. Can you please help me understand issue with the script

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
export SRC_FILE_PATH="s3://merch-dev/Vendor/Orgzp/2017/11/21/"
for files in `aws s3 ls ${SRC_FILE_PATH} | awk '{print $4}'`
do
  find $files -type f -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c 'echo $1;gunzip -c $1 | wc -l' dummy {} \;
done
```

**Error:**

```
find: `part-00000-9f2e072e-b555-4857-b16d-e1236ea98d0e.csv.gz': No such file or directory
find: `part-00000-9f33e66b-418d-4c66-90ae-64cd91665f38.csv.gz': No such file or directory
find: `part-00000-9f6d1d0b-4f01-4662-826e-b5396221220e.csv.gz': No such file or directory
```

Comment: sorry, as im unable to format the code.

Comment: What files are actually in the directory?

Comment: These files are in S3 Bucket in SRC_FILE_PATH, i understand that for the find command these *.gz has to be present on unix directory. but is there a way to read from the S3 and get the counts.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally confused now.  Are you getting the errors above when trying to read the S3, or on a local directory?

Comment: when im reading from S3.

Comment: Ok, so which files as actually in the directory (ie, if you run the script, which files would you expect it to see)

Comment: It should gunzip and check the counts for .csv, hope im clear now.

Comment: Your error lists three files.  Are those the only files in the directory?

Comment: In total , 300 files are present in the S3 path mentioned. as a sample, i provided 3 files.

Comment: It seems to be passing only the filename to gunzip, not the whole path.  Can you test by printing the value that's being passed to gunzip?

Comment: its printing the path correctly, but with error "No such file or directory". I believe the issue is with the quotes ` in above error message.

Comment: It's printing the file, but not the full path.  Is the path being passed to gunzip?

Comment: for files in `aws s3 ls ${SRC_FILE_PATH}'/' | awk '{print $4}'`
do
  echo ${SRC_FILE_PATH}'/'${files}
done

Comment: sorry for trouble, trying to provide proper formatting of code, but helpless..

Comment: In above code, it prints the files as expected.

Comment: That prints the full path, because you explicitly print it.  Is gunzip getting `file`, or `/dir/file`?

Comment: I think its getting the file.

Comment: Surely it needs to file WITH the full path?  That's what I'm asking - print/show what gunzip is getting.

Comment: running late to home..thanks alot for your time will test and keep this thread updated.

Comment: fl_line_count=`gunzip ${SRC_FILE_PATH}'/'${files} -c | wc -l`, still shows

Comment: gzip: s3://merch-dev/Vendor/Orgzp/2017/11/21/part-00000-a172df63-03a6-4bd9-b820-8db8cb9846ce.csv.gz: No such file or directory
Line Count: 0

Comment: am i missing anything?

Comment: Can `gunzip` correctly handle an s3 URL?

Comment: I don't think it can.  You're using the s3 commandline util to list the files, but then trying to use `gunzip` on a file location it has no idea how to use.  Look at this: https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/25559308/How+to+use+the+S3+command-line+tool+Mac+OSX+Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're retrieving the list of files using the AWS commandline utility, and then attempting to use `gunzip` on those locations.  `gunzip` is a utility meant to be used on a local filesystem, and does not know how to handle a file location with `s3://...`.

You need to either:

1. Get the list of files, copy them over one by one, and then gunzip them, or
2. Map the S3 location to a local folder (using something like [this](https://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/) approach), and then use `gunzip`

Comment: I was going through and feel 2nd approach is better , will try thanks for you r time.